# jQuery formatting a table that is show/hide

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm very new to jQuery so keep that in mind. I've got the page working with the jQuery and I have it setup the way I want it. The problem I'm coming in to now is that I cannot format the table that is in the hidden area.

The HTM:L

```
                <div class="flip">Screening</div>
                <div class="panel">
                    <table style="width:500px">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:100px">Test<td>
                            <td style="width:100px">Test<td>
                            <td style="width:100px">Test<td>
                            <td style="width:100px">Test<td>
                            <td style="width:100px"><a href="patient_profile.php?patientid=' .$patientid. '"><img src="images/document.png" width="33px" height="25px"><td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('.flip').click(function () {
 $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(200)
});
```

The CSS:

```
.panel,.flip
{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#e5eecc;
  border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
.panel
{
  width: 500px;
  padding:5px;
  display:none;
}

.panel th {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgb(34,122,174);
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(6, 23, 38);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.panel tr td {
  color: rgb(6, 23, 38);
  border: 2px solid rgb(6, 23, 38);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

.panel tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.panel tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(217, 226, 243);
}

.panel a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.panel img {
  border: none;
}
```

Like I said, it's working as I want it to, the problem is simply in the formatting of that table that is part of the jQuery function to show/hide. It correctly shows/hides how I want it to but it's not taking any of the table formatting from the CSS. The CSS is working for the .flip and .panel but nothing related to the table.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TnC4A/)

Comment: `.panel th` you have no `th` elements. And your closing cell tags are wrong. And your image is missing the closing anchor tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D6H4V/ - seems fine, what is "wrong"?

Answer (score 0):

create a class that has the styling properties you want in your css file, but DO NOT apply it to your class.

When you show the table, you can use jQuery to add a class to an element in the html document, thus you can add the class to the table! Then it will get your styling properties :D

the code to add the class :

```
$("#table").addClass("table_style");
```

but you will need to give your table an ID so you can select it.

EDIT: FIXED YOUR CODE

your code is wrong, it should be like this :

```
<div class="flip">Screening</div>
     <div class="panel">
          <table style="width:500px">
              <tr>
                  <td style="width:100px">Test</td>
                  <td style="width:100px">Test</td>
                  <td style="width:100px">Test</td>
                  <td style="width:100px">Test</td>
                  <td style="width:100px"><a href="patient_profile.php?patientid=' .$patientid. '">
                      <img src="images/document.png" width="33px" height="25px" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: So add the .addClass to the jquery file, and create an independent class for the table?